# Same jar Files in EJB & EAR project

Tags: exception

How can I use the same jar files in EJB and EAR projects?

- **EJB** ---> Jar files to add build path in Eclipse.
- **EAR** ---> EJB project & jar files to add Java EE dependencies.

Otherwise I'm getting a ***class cast Exception*** for what seems to be identical classes.

Example:

com.sample.es.ra.**EsCciConnectionFactory** cannot be cast to com.sample.es.ra.**EsCciConnectionFactory**

Comment: You only need them once, either in EJB or EAR, but not both.

Comment: But how can I deployment that EJB project? Then only am using both. The EJB project inside of EAR project. Give any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

In short: add the jar files as dependencies to your EJB project and the resulting EJB jar to your EAR project.

You can do it differently depending on the build management system. With ant, use `depends` attribute for your targets, with maven, define the EAR project as `parent` for your EJB project.

Ant [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/EJBTutorialfromJBossantscriptforEJBpackaging.htm)

Maven [example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring.html)

Comment: I added dependencies to my EJB project. But when am running that EAR project, i'm getting "No Class Found Exception". What I do?

Comment: @shanmuga to answer that, I need to know, what you are doing - how is the dependency of your EAR for your EJB defined? Are you following the examples?

Comment: I'm not using ANT or Maven. only for Eclipse project. I want to use EJB project to jboss AS7 deployment folder. So I need EAR or WAR files. Then only I done, create one EAR project and use this EJB project to that EAR project. But the dependencies are problem. Now, Are you understand my problem or not? plz help me.

Comment: @shanmuga then you are implicitly using ant ;) But no problem - have you defined the built ejb.jar as a dependency for the ear project?

Comment: ya. I'm defined the EJB.jar as a dependency for the EAR project. Any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: @shanmuga - if your EAR project is a proper "eclipse EAR project", do you have an `application.xml` inside it's 'META-INF' folder, listing the ejb jar like this : <application>
  <display-name>master-application</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejb1.jar</ejb>
  </module>...
?

Comment: @shanmuga - I have always used explicit build scripts for EARs, so it might be rather difficult to spot the exact problem with the eclipse config - there are so many possibilities

Comment: This is my application.xml.</p><?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>EsJacamarEAR</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>EsJacamarEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <connector>EsCciConnectionFactory.jar.rar</connector>
  </module>
</application>

Comment: @shanmuga - application.xml looks good actually. Then I must resign, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Jar files that are to be shared by all modules in an EAR archive can be placed in the `\lib` folder that's in the root of the EAR.

In Eclipse, using WTP's `Enterprise Application Project` it will look like this in project explorer:

```
foo_ear <--- the EAR project
    EarContent
        lib <--- Put your jars here
            bar.jar
            kaz.jar
foo_ejb <--- the EJB project
    src
        com.example
            Something.java
    EAR Libraries <--- lists libraries "found" in root EAR's /lib
        bar.jar
        kaz.jar
```